# Ebean RawSql does not allow named parameters in "case when" clause

Tags: java, sql, playframework, ebean

I've encountered a problem while working with Ebean RawSql query. Here's a simple example.

```
Finder<Long, Test> finder= new Finder<>(Test.class);

String query = "SELECT t.ID AS t_id, t.NAME as t_name, (SELECT CASE WHEN t.NAME = :name THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sort_priority FROM test ORDER BY sort_priority";

RawSql raw = RawSqlBuilder.parse(query)
.columnMapping("t_id", "id")
.columnMapping("t_name", "name")
.columnMappingIgnore("sort_priority")
.create();
        
Query<Test> testQuery = finder.query().setRawSql(raw).setParameter("name", "Test1");
```

But when I execute this query I get an error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':name THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sort_priority FROM test  ORDER BY sort_priorit' at line 1
```

If I use ? instead of named parameters everything is okay. But can I somehow fix it with keeping named parameter and "case when" clause at the same time?